# Show legend on plot

Tags: plotting

I have a series of curve I'm plotting using `ListPlot`.  For each plot I'm changing a variable called `X`. Is there anyway I could show `X` above each plot? Not like the legend function since it shows it on the side or above.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

[`PlotLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html) does it!

```
Table[ListPlot[Table[X Sin[n/Pi], {n, 30}], PlotLabel -> X], {X, 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use helpers as:

```
text1 = "My Title";
text2 = "My other Title";
text3 = "More Text";
text4 = "Well ...";
```

ans use'm within ListPlot,

```
lp1 = ListPlot[data
   , PlotLabel -> text1
   , AxesLabel -> {x, y}
   , ImageSize -> Medium];

lp2 = ListPlot[data
   , PlotLabel -> text2
   , Frame -> True
   , FrameLabel -> {x, y}
   , ImageSize -> Medium];

lp3 = ListPlot[data
   , PlotLabel -> text3
   , AxesLabel -> {x, y}
   , ImageSize -> Medium];

lp4 = ListPlot[data
   , PlotLabel -> text4
   , Frame -> True
   , FrameLabel -> {x, y}
   , ImageSize -> Medium];
```

[image]

`ListPlot` is a pretty powerful tool. The Documentation Center (via F1) has some great examples.

```
?? ListPlot
```

... shows you the most important informations in a compact overview:

[image]

Note the difference between no Frame `Frame->True`.